# Mutliple filters on rows of a DataFrame based on list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
0   0   a   361
1   0   b   92
2   0   c   909
3   0   d   114
4   0   e   914
5   0   f   732
6   1   a   738
7   1   b   744
8   1   c   345
9   1   d   141
10  1   e   771
11  1   f   206
12  2   a   367
13  2   b   133
14  2   c   509
15  2   d   968
16  2   e   527
17  2   f   288
18  3   a   231
19  3   b   673
20  3   c   925
21  3   d   760
22  3   e   491
23  3   f   741
```

I wish to filter out a few rows (from two columns `Col1` and `Col2`)based on a given list like the one below,

```
[[0, 'a'],[0, 'd'],[1, 'b'],[2, 'a'],[3, 'e']]
```

So this should filter the DataFrame and give me:

```
 Col1 Col2 Col3
0   0   a   37
3   0   d   37
7   1   b   143
12  2   a   170
22  3   e   46
```

I can't do a value-wise filter nor can I use loops because in my case I've a huge dataframe. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a simple merge.

```
l = [[0, 'a'],[0, 'd'],[1, 'b'],[2, 'a'],[3, 'e']]
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['Col1', 'Col2']))
```

Output

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   0       a       361
1   0       d       114
2   1       b       744
3   2       a       367
4   3       e       491
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a boolean mask with two conditions:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, "a", 361],
    [0, "b", 92],
    [0, "c", 909],
    [0, "d", 114],
    [0, "e", 914],
    [0, "f", 732],
    [1, "a", 738],
    [1, "b", 744],
    [1, "c", 345],
    [1, "d", 141],
    [1, "e", 771],
    [1, "f", 206],
    [2, "a", 367],
    [2, "b", 133],
    [2, "c", 509],
    [2, "d", 968],
    [2, "e", 527],
    [2, "f", 288],
    [3, "a", 231],
    [3, "b", 673],
    [3, "c", 925],
    [3, "d", 760],
    [3, "e", 491],
    [3, "f", 741]
], columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
)

l = [[0, 'a'],
     [0, 'd'],
     [1, 'b'],
     [2, 'a'],
     [3, 'e']]

filt = ((df['Col1'].isin(l[:][0])) & (df['Col2'].isin(l[:][1])))
print(df[filt])
```

Returning:

```
   Col1 Col2  Col3
3     0    d   114
```

Or just one of the conditions being met:

```
filt = ((df['Col1'].isin(l[:][0])) | (df['Col2'].isin(l[:][1])))
print(df[filt])
```

Giving:

```
    Col1 Col2  Col3
0      0    a   361
1      0    b    92
2      0    c   909
3      0    d   114
4      0    e   914
5      0    f   732
9      1    d   141
15     2    d   968
21     3    d   760
```

If this causes a memory overflow for you, consider moving to pyspark from pandas. You can run command: `spark.createDataFrame` for example.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, Gustav.

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy the coding :)